# Keepalive time - cannot reduce below one minute in C++

Tags: c++, tcp, keep-alive

I implement a keepalive time in a C++ application that is writing to a TCP port via the code below.  It's not shown, but I actually do a check for a valid return status to verify that setting the options work.

```
int option = 1;
int keepalive_intvl = 1;
int keepalive_count = 1;
int keepalive_idle = 1;

setsockopt(the_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, &option, sizeof (int) );
setsockopt(the_socket, SOL_TCP, TCP_KEEPINTVL, &keepalive_intvl, sizeof(int));
setsockopt(the_socket, SOL_TCP, TCP_KEEPCNT, &keepalive_count, sizeof(int));
setsockopt(the_socket, SOL_TCP, TCP_KEEPIDLE, &keepalive_idle, sizeof(int));
```

My application is writing to a TCP port, and attempts a write a few times per second.

```
// write null packet to determine if connection is still good
return ( send( GetDescriptor(),(char*)NULL, 0, 0 ) != -1 );
```

Whenever I close the other, input connection, it takes one minute for my application to report that the connection is down, based on the test above.  If I have a `SIGPIPE` handler function, it takes one minute for that to be called as well.

Every documentation that I've seen indicates that the keepalive parameters are in seconds, not minutes.  But I cannot get the dropped connection to be detected below one minute.

I also tried changing the system variables related to keepalive discussed at [tldp.org](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/usingkeepalive.html), but to no avail.

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_time
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_intvl
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_probes
```

Is this behavior controlled by another system parameter? Are the keepalive parameters actually in minutes, contrary to some documentation?  Is there a certain function I should look for in the code that could affect this timeout parameter?

Comment: option is an int not int32

Comment: @QuentinUK, they're the same in my code.  Nevertheless, edited for clarity.

Comment: Have you tried to actually check the return code of `setsockopt()`?

Comment: @VladLazarenko, I have.  I should probably specify that in question.

Comment: Keepalive for detecting connection loss doesn't make much sense anyway, if you ask me. It's unreliable and misleading at best. It's useful to keep a stateful firewall "warm", or for keeping a dialup link connected, but surely not for ensuring that a connection is alive.

Comment: You're adjusting how often you send keepalives, but I think the connection only gets closed after the timeout period, which you're not changing.

Comment: @Damon what did you suggest for detecting connection loss?

Comment: @AliAmiri: Connection loss is not easily detected at all, as the underlying protocol (IP) is not connection-oriented. Usually, you will get an error rather quickly trying to send (if, say, the server on the other side crashes). However, it's perfectly possible that you only get a timeout error after _minutes_ (e.g. if ICMP 3 is lost). Still, sending/receiving regularly and reacting to an error code is the best and most reliable method. TCP keepalives are by default sent every half hour if I recall correctly, so the connection might go up and down 10 times in between without you knowing.

Comment: @Damon tnx for this information, because of our server architecture I couldn't send data from server to client, so I found a way with reading buffer in client to find out that data is sent our not you here is my soloution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16145135/how-to-detect-tcp-client-connect-to-server-in-c/16187437

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to change the overall keepalive time via the `TCP_LINGER2` value.

Whenever I close the input tcp process, I use `netstat -an` to get the following lines.

```
tcp        1      0 127.0.0.1:32962         127.0.0.1:7780          CLOSE_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:7780          127.0.0.1:32962         FIN_WAIT2
```

I can change this `FIN_WAIT2` time two different ways.

On the system level, according to this [link](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~brecht/servers/tcp.html), I can change it by modifying a system file as follows:

```
% cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_fin_timeout
60

[To change this to 3 seconds]
# echo "3" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_fin_timeout
```

My output TCP application indicates that the connection is dropped in about four seconds (I imagine 3 for the wait time, 1 for the keepalive idle).

I can also change this on the individual socket level in code. In the file `/usr/include/netinet/tcp.h`, I see the following

```
#define TCP_LINGER2  8  /* Life time of orphaned FIN-WAIT-2 state */
```

So, adding the following in my code,

```
int wait_time = 3;
setsockopt(the_socket, SOL_TCP, TCP_LINGER2, &wait_time,sizeof(int));
```

will have the same affect as varying the system parameter.

I do agree with the other answers in that application-level keepalives is really the way to go.  And, as mentioned [here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/05/detection-of-half-open-dropped.html),

> RFC 1122, section 4.2.3.6 indicates that acknowledgements for TCP
>   keepalives without data may not be transmitted reliably by routers;
>   this may cause valid connections to be dropped. Furthermore, TCP/IP
>   stacks are not required to support keepalives at all (and many
>   embedded stacks do not), so this solution may not translate to other
>   platforms.

However, in a non-test environment, I don't have access to the TCP inputs in which I can implement the other side of the application-level keepalives, so TCP keepalives may be my only option.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is an application-layer keep-alive; that is, send a no-operation (NOP) message every X seconds and expect a reasonably quick NOP-acknowledgement (NOP-ACK).  Also, if your remote connection close is "graceful", then your `send` should unblock nearly immediately.  If it's not graceful (e.g. a network element failed), then your application-layer keep-alive will detect the loss at your next time X+(expected response time)...

Comment: Any kind of application-layer keepalive for TCP is bound to have problems eventually, it has difficulties to adapt to RTT's, jitter, temporary loss of connection, ... . having 2 time-critical layers is always a bad idea (hence why tunnels almost always use UDP). Besides you're going to mix both application and keepalive data in one stream, which is very error-prone.

Comment: RTT and jitter are negligible when your keep-alive is on the order of seconds.  If temporary loss of connection isn't handled by the TCP layer, your application has to deal with that anyway.  I'll agree that if it's time-critical, all the extra traffic imposed by TCP-acks is wasted and UDP is a better choice.

Comment: The problem is, I don't really have access to the other end (the other process listening). I do in a test environment, but I won't always.  But yes, I agree, application level keepalives would be my preferred way.

Answer (score 1):

> TCP_KEEPCNT (since Linux 2.4)
>   The maximum number of keepalive probes TCP should send before dropping the connection. This option should not be used in code intended to be portable.

Maybe that could be the reason. You could implement your own keep alive in your application, it should be pretty easy. Just start to poke the other end if no application data or keep-alive "heart-beat" comes.