# how to detect tcp client connect to server in c++

Tags: c++, linux, networking, tcp, tcpclient

I have a tcp client/server, and I want to detect connection loss in client side; because my client have multiple interfaces and at a time I connected to server with one of them, I want to know how to detect connection loss in client side so that I could connect my tcp client with another interface to the server and if all of them are down I store my data in text files. I googled it and I already seen keep alive but it's not what I want.

if it is important my project is in linux and code is in c++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way that I found is to check buffer, if buffer is empty it means that your TCP client send the packet to the TCP server successfully and you can send the next packet; for checking the buffer you can use `SIOCOUTQ`; its very easy to use and show you how much data you have in your buffer.

Comment: Cool idea.  How are you avoiding a race condition, if you check that ioctl too soon?  Also [SIOCOUTQ appears to be Linux-specific](http://blog.netherlabs.nl/articles/2009/01/18/the-ultimate-so_linger-page-or-why-is-my-tcp-not-reliable) implies this isn't a solution for a Windows developer.

Comment: @SergeIvanoff I know it's not supported in windows but as I mentioned in the question I'm coding in linux and I seek solution for my problem; I didnt ask this question to solve others problems!
if I check ioctl too soon I'll wait for it to response if I get error I didnt just close my socket if ioctl didnt response but I will wait for almost 1 minute and if in this time my data still remains in the buffer I'll close my socket.

Answer (score 1):

Try to read from the socket. When the socket closes, the read will fail, giving you simple detection. You can do this in a dedicated detection thread so that your main thread doesn't block.

Comment: if an interface loss it's connection to the internet dose this close the socket?(my interfaces all are 3g)

Comment: Yes. It may take a little time for the remote machine to notice (but you want that time to be taken, in order to prevent false socket closes due to network issues between the two machines).

Comment: Why would you ever open a connection and _not_ have a read thread? I don't mean in a separate thread. I mean, what's the point of having a client connection if you don't read from the socket?

Comment: @SergeIvanoff not every application requires bidirectional communications, and it's also reasonable to have an application protocol that, for example, reads once at the beginning and then enters a loop of (long delay for processing / etc), write -- no need to read in the mean time (except if you wish to detect remote disconnect in order to abort the processing work).

Comment: True, thanks.  But a read may sit indefinitely and not return a failed response it the socket isn't terminated, unless you code in a timeout.

Comment: You don't need a timeout in your read necessarily. Once your local system knows the socket is not longer valid, it will unblock the read, causing it to return (with an error). The local system won't know immediately if the remote crashes (or is disconnected from the network, etc.) so a timeout can still be useful for improved responsiveness, depending on application needs.

Comment: @mah I read from the socket but it seems there is no timeout for that; it takes too long and still nothing returned from read function!

Answer (score 1):

TCP connections are designed to be error correcting and not time critical.  This error correction includes network timeouts.

Reads and Write will not fail until the socket is actually closed, which may not be for a very long time.

The only way for a client to decide if a connection has timed-out is for the client to detect that it hasn't received any messages for a specified time, and manually close the socket.

That's what Keep Alive messages are for.

Comment: My client will not receive any messages at all! because of our design only the client will send messages to the server! if my client get messages it would be very easy for me to detect client and server connection!

Comment: In that case, there is no way.  If there is a network delay, TCP buffers messages in an attempt to recover once the connection is re-established.  I'm sure there's some why that you'll get a "buffer full" message if you write too much data, but that depends on the underlying network buffer sizes.  Your server design has to change to send out keep alive (or status messages, if you like).

Comment: I solved the problem without keepalive and other responses from server.